# Background process in Java

Tags: java, background-process

I have been preparing for OCP exam in Java 7. The book I am reading I come accross something I don't understand completely.

That is,

> If the JVM is invoked indirectly by IDE, or if the JVM is invoked from
>   a **background process**, then the method call `System.console()` will
>   fail and return null.

In what case and how do you invoke JVM from the background process?. Can someone elaborate on that?
Best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you are on a UNIX system, and you run a program that can ask for two operands and produce their sum.  If you invoke it as:

```bash
/home/ucas> java -jar add.jar
Please enter the first summand:
42
Please enter the second summand:
17
The sum is 59.
```

Now suppose you run it in the background:

```bash
/home/ucas> java -jar add.jar &
java.lang.NullPointerException at Add.main(Add.java:17)
....
```

Looking at Add.java, you see:

```java
Console console = System.console(); // 16
Reader  reader  = console.reader(); // 17
```

The process is detached from the terminal, so `console` will be `null`. The stack trace is printed to standard error, which isn't redirected.

Answer (score 1):

This is as per the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Console.html)

> Whether a virtual machine has a console is dependent upon the underlying platform and also upon the manner in which the virtual machine is invoked. If the virtual machine is started from an interactive command line without redirecting the standard input and output streams then its console will exist and will typically be connected to the keyboard and display from which the virtual machine was launched. **If the virtual machine is started automatically, for example by a background job scheduler, then it will typically not have a console.**

IDEs like Eclipse runs your app as a background process and not as a top-level process with a system console.

Answer (score 1):

It is just saying that if you launch a JVM from your IDE or as a child process of your main Java process, it will not have a console attached to it.

- in the case of an IDE, the IDE's console is used.
- in the case of a sub process, you need to redirect the input/output streams to the main process if you want the sub process to use the main process's console.

Answer (score 0):

If you invoke JVM from another process. You wont have accesss to console. Eg. you may run a java program from within another java program using Runtime.exec(...)